# Вылетает WPF приложение без всякого указания на ошибку

Tags: c#, wpf, исключения

Весь код заключен в `Try - Catch` конструкции с выводом текста эксепшна, но по непонятным причинам вылетает через какое-то время (10-20 мин) безо всяких сообщений. 
.net Framework 4, из сторонних сборок использую WPF ToolKit и MS Ribbon. 
В чем может быть проблема?

ps. Даже в режиме отладки в Visual Studio просто через какое-то время приложение завершает свою работу (прекращается отладка) и все.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать глобальный `try-catch`, установите через `Ctrl-Alt-E` все возможные типы эксепшнов и проведите эксперимент еще раз.

Comment: Отметил все, вот результат: 
Не удалось загрузить сборку с выводимым именем "RibbonControlsLibrary.Under Line Elegant" в контекст связывания "Load" домена приложения с идентификатором 1. Причина сбоя: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "RibbonControlsLibrary.Under Line Elegant, Version=4.0.0.11019, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" или один из зависимых от них компонентов. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Сборку удалял и заново подключал, итог тот же.

Comment: @fundottz При запуске эта (именно с такой версией) сборка есть в `GAC'e` или в папке с приложением?

Comment: забыл добавить: результат этот возникает при построении приложения, а как вылетал после без всякого предупреждения, так и вылетает.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, не знаю как в GAC сборку положить, поначалу на WPF Toolkit ругалась студия, что сборка должна быть в GAC. В папке с приложением в bin\debug лежат все сборки

Comment: попробуй WPF Toolkit собрать дополнительным проектом в своем решении. может, поможет и там ексепшн вывалится))